# EF Core 5 with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have installed an Linux SQL Server instance in my OS X using a docker container and I hace connected to this localhost instance with VS Code

[image: VS Code]

But I need to connect to it in VS for Mac to develop my EF Core Project and I don't know if is it possible because when I try this in my DbContext

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Boletus;Integrated Security=True")
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
```

I get this exception

[image: exception]

Any idea please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost, 1433; Database=Boletus;User=sa; Password=Windows2021!")
.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }, LogLevel.Information)
.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

Thanks